# Can REST applied using grpc?

Tags: rest, http, https, grpc

As much as REST and HTTP1.1 go hand in hand, technically REST is independent of HTTP (and its GET, POST, PUT... methods).

So I think it is possible to apply REST architectural style/constraints using GRPC.

I think a lot of the "GRPC vs REST" comparisons I've seen are wrong in this regard.

Is there a REST architectural style constraint that we cannot apply using GRPC?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a REST architectural style constraint that we cannot apply using GRPC?

My primary concern would be the [uniform interface constraint](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5):

> REST is defined by four interface constraints: identification of resources; manipulation of resources through representations; self-descriptive messages; and, **hypermedia as the engine of application state**.

(emphasis added).

On the web, we have application/html, a general purpose media type that can express links and forms that "everybody" understands the same way (and one that supports the optional [code-on-demand](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7) constraint).

For gRPC, this interface constraint is satisfied by ...?

---

It may help to review this comment in Fielding's dissertation:

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction.

Comment: Good point with the interface constraint and hypermedia as the engine of application state. Regarding your question *For gRPC, this interface constraint is satisfied by ...?* I think the answer is that the constraint is not satisfied. Most commonly gRPC uses an Interface Definition Language (usually Protobuf) for defining interfaces. The [Wikipedia article on HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) even uses Interface Definition Languages as an contrast example to HATEOAS.

Comment: If we are talking about an http/RESTful api that returns HTML, your answer is valid: 'we have application/html, a general purpose media type that can express links and forms that "everybody" understands the same way.'


But we can also implement RESTful in a http/RESTful api that returns JSON. In this case, how do we apply Heteoas? There is no general purpose types that can express links and forms that "everybody" understands the same way in the http/RESTful api's JSON response (just like GRPC response).

Comment: "In this case, how do we apply Hateoas?" you use a media type with additional constraints as your engine of application state.  See: https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/

Answer (score 0):

`REST` stands for "Representational State Transfer", while `gRPC` stands for "gRPC Remote Procedure Calls" (yes, it's a recursive acronym).

From the name alone, you can see that those are not meant to do the same thing:

- `REST` is meant to transfer state (POST the state of a new resource, GET to fetch the state, ...)
- `gRPC` is meant to send commands (or, as it were, calling procedures)

You can absolutely build a set of procedures in `gRPC` to fetch and update the state of resources, but it would be difficult to call that `REST`